yup validation problem when pasting text with ctrl+v
<Field
   name="content"> 
    {({ field, form }) => (
   <CustomReactQuill
   value={field.value}
   fieldName={field.name}
   form={form}
   />
    )}
</Field>

    content: Yup.string()
      .required('field is required'),

This is a code snippet, when I type something on the keyboard into the content field everything works fine, the live preview works fine. But when I try to empty content field to paste some text (ctrl+v) the live preview does not work. Only the text appears when I click on another part of the page or when I type some text from the keyboard.
When I remove the validation to the 'content' field pasting with ctrl+v works fine. Is it possible to make pasting text work with this validation?

Hi @Daniel can you replicate your code on a codesandbox for easy understanding? That way we can help better

setTimeout(() => {
form.handleSubmit();
}, 100);
it helped.

Paste briefly blurs the element, then pastes the text into the field before refocusing the element.  The paste action triggers onChange, which can make things confusing, since the onBlur event is unexpected.
